How can I validate a radio input with JavaScript?
I have a problem, I want to validate a input type="radio" with vanilla JavaScript (probably using document.getElementById()), based on ECMAScript. How do I do it?
Here is my HTML:


label { display: block; }
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
  <span>Male</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
  <span>Female</span>
</label>



I don't know how to create a function to verify if the radio button is checked or not. I saw some posts talking about this, but all of them used some frameworks or another solutions, but I just want to use Vanilla JavaScript.

Does this answer your question? How to validate radio button using javascript

For what it's worth, your label around "Female" is tied to an input with id="others" rather than id="female". You could easily pre-select one. Or use querySelectorAll() to gather your radios, put them into an array, and use array.some() to determine if one is checked.

You can use querySelector, because they are the same name. which one checked we can find it。 then we retrieve the id or get value


const radioControl =
  document.querySelector('[name="gender"]:checked');

console.log(radioControl?.value);
label { display: block; }
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked />
  <span>Male</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
  <span>Female</span>
</label>




One can access a radio node-list via all of a form's named items.
The selected value can be immediately read from the node-list via nodeList.value.
And the selected radio-control can be filtered from the node-lists array representation.


function handleRadioControlCheckedState(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const radioNodeList =
    evt.currentTarget.form.elements['gender'];

  const checkedControl =
    [...radioNodeList].filter(({ checked }) => checked).at(0);

  console.log('\nradio node-list ...', radioNodeList);
  console.log('checked control ...', checkedControl);
}

document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', handleRadioControlCheckedState);
label { display: block; margin: 0 0 4px 0; }
button { margin: 8px 0 0 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 80%; min-height: 100%; }
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
    <span>Male</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
    <span>Female</span>
  </label>

  <button>Which is checked?</button>
</form>




Did you try something like:
let male= document.getElementById('male').value;

if(male){
//your code
}

Or
if(document.getElementById("male").checked = true){
//your code
}


